# pass a variable to php page via dropzone url?

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

i have this code and im asking about how to carry a "myvar" as a PHP variable via the URL with the dropzone below

```
$(".uploadform").dropzone({ 
    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg",

url: 'uploading.php?myvar=, <<<
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 10, // Number of files at a time
    maxFilesize: 10, //in MB
```

im asking how to pass a php variable by the URL above to the page Uploading.php ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to the URL string, don't forget to use `urlencode` if it might contain characters not allowed in URLs. 
Here is an example, assuming your variable name in php is `$myvar` and your javascript code is in `.php` file

```
$(".uploadform").dropzone({ 
    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg",
    url: 'uploading.php?myvar=<?= urlencode($myvar); ?>',
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 10, // Number of files at a time
    maxFilesize: 10, //in MB
});
```

Than you can access this variable in `Upload.php` as `$_GET['myvar']`

Comment: sorry for the mistake .. i meant by pp is a php variable :( , plz could u plz edit the code to transfer a php variable ?

Comment: @user3526074 Edited example